# SSIS Package: differences between OnTaskFailed and OnError events?

Tags: events, event-handling, ssis

What is the difference between 'OnTaskFailed' and 'OnError' events?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The OnError event is raised for any error, while the OnTaskFailed event is only raised when a task fails.  While these two may often occur together there are certain circumstances where they would not.  If the task had its `ForcedExecutionResult` property set to Completion/Success or the `MaximumErrorCount` value was raised above the number of errors that occurred are some examples of when these events wouldn't overlap.